# EditText как в vk

Tags: android, android-edittext

Как сделать такую же полосу с кнопками, как в приложении vk при создании поста?
Эта панелька еще должна подниматься, когда выдвигается клавиатура, чтобы всегда быть видимой.

---

[image: Вк пост.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EditText` растянем по ширине и длине экрана, ниже будет синяя панель с 5-ю `ImageView`как на скриншоте. Поменяете картинки, замените на `ImageButton` и вот вам счастье. Тэг `Space` должен быть размещен между всеми `view`, которые нужно выровнить.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Df"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#0953AE"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ну и в тэг вашей `Activity` в `AndroidManifest`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47695/discussion-on-answer-by---edittext---vk).